# Get an ID value as a string from a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I would like to know how I can get a value from a webview.
For example, to load a value into the webview I use:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value='"+ user + "';");
```

Now I would like to read some text from a certain ID from a webpage.
Something like:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("www.example.com");
myWebView.getUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').toString(user);");
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Since KitKat (API 19), the `WebView` class provides the method [`evaluateJavascript`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) that allows to execute javascript and get the return values.

For olders API, you can still bind javascript to your Android Java code ([look here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript))

So, you will implement a Javascript interface class and add it to your `WebView` and then call something like

```
 myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyJavascriptInterface.getValue(document.getElementById('username').value);");
```

This will call the method `getValue` (this is a custom function, it is up to you to rename it as you want) in your class that is used as a Javascript interface, and change `MyJavascriptInterface` with the name you specified in `addJavascriptInterface`.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can. `getElementById('username').Value`

Comment: and how do i put that element into a string? Like String user=""; getElementById('username').Value(user); ?

Comment: String user = myWebView.getElementById('username').value;

Comment: can't do that, getting Invalid character constant on 'username'

Comment: well, can you post anything you get `var user = myWebView.getElementById('username').value;`

Comment: i'm using this on java, not javascript, i'm trying to extract an element id to a string from a webpage loaded on a webview into my java. hope this helps

Comment: what's the type of instance myWebView ?

Comment: It's a Webview, i just named it myWebView. Like: WebView myWebView;